# ZEND overload form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Instead of my former viewscript, which showed my recordset as a table:

```
$i=1;
foreach($this->aktermine as $termin) : 
?>

<tr>
<td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->nr);?></td>
<td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->kopfnr);?></td>
<td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->datum);?></td>
<td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->zeit);?></td>
<td class="row_<?PHP echo $i % 2;?>"><?php echo $this->escape($termin->thema);?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<?php 

$i=$i+1;
endforeach;
```

I built a form with decorators in the style, the next snippet shows:

```
$kopfnr=$this->CreateElement('text','kopfnr')
             ->setAttrib('size', '5');
$kopfnr->setDecorators(array(
               'ViewHelper',
               'Description',
               'Errors',
               array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td'))
               ));
```

How can I use the form instead of the viewscript in the sameway? I want to see all related records and additional have the possibility to add a new record without leaving the page.

Here is my indexcontroller:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Aktermine();
$this->view->form = $form;
$logenr = $this->_getParam('nr', 0);
if ($logenr > 0) {          
    $aktermine=new Application_Model_DbTable_Aktermine();
    $select=$aktermine->select()->where('kopfnr = ?',  $logenr) ;
    $this->view->aktermine = $aktermine->fetchAll($select);     
}
```

First step should be: Showing all existing records in the right form fields
Second Step: An Add action, which does not leave the page, but if it is possible, adds a new line at the end of the existing records, where the user can fill in new data in a new datarecord.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use JavaScript to add an empty row at the end of your table plus AJAX to send the new entry back to your controller.

Comment: I´m not really sure how to get the values back. Can you offer a sample code?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, this is what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - the URL will look like your-domain/?controller=your-db-handler&action=add-new-entry
If you are not using jQuery (or any other JavaScript-library), you'll have to use XMLHttpRequest().